# Pending comment

Tags: templates, comments, comment-form, template-manager

think a stupid question but don't see it. I have two channels with comment possibilities one the comments are pending and the other directly post the comment on the site. I want to pending both but don't see where or how I can do that. I'm logged off

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "Moderate Comments" setting in the channel settings. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/channels.html#settings-tab